# python 3 ttk Treeview item set

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I've been building a multi-column listbox using code I found on the web - ttk_multicolumn_listbox2.py.

Using double-click bind, I've determined which row I've highlighted, and get data from that row.  Here's my code:

```
# .focus() gives me the row ID I've double-clicked on
#
cRowId = ttk.Treeview.focus( my_listbox.tree )
#
# .item() gives me a dictionary of that row's info
#
dicTemp = ttk.Treeview.item( my_listbox.tree, cRowId )
print( dicTemp )
```

Here's what's printed:

```
{'image': '', 'tags': '', 'values': [5, 'Dracula', '', '', 'Stoker, Bram', '   425,106', '2015-01-30', 'Y', 'Y'], 'text': '', 'open': 0}
```

Great! Using the 'values' key, I can get the information I need.

After I'm done working on that data, some of the values have changed, and I want to put the changed data back into the Treeview, so the user can see the updated data.  I can get the changed data back into the list that's in the dictionary. That's easy. But how to get it back into the Treeview...?

Reading the documentation about .item(), it says:

> item(item, option=None, **kw)
>
> Query or modify the options for the specified item.
>
> If no options are given, a dict with options/values for the item is returned. If option is specified then the value for that option is returned. Otherwise, sets the options to the corresponding values as given by kw.

What the heck is "**kw"???  I'm guessing keyword?

FINALLY - the question: How do I get that changed data back into the Treeview, using .item()?

ANSWER:  I guess it's appropriate to answer one's own question  :-)

See my comment below as to where I found the clue.  Here's the solution:

```
#
# write the changes back to the Treeview
#
ttk.Treeview.item( my_listbox.tree, cRowId, values = dictTemp['values'])
```

Worked like a charm!  Thanks to everyone who puts in an answer or comment here at stackoverflow.  I appreciate all the help!

Comment: I've answered my own question. A python program gave me the clue I needed. (http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/ttk-gsoc/samples/ttkcalendar.py)